# How do I throw up Windows tray notifications?

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to use tray notifications in my Python script.  I don't care about portability, so I'd be fine with using `ctypes` and some of the pywin32 modules, but I don't know what calls to use.

My script would be running in the background the whole while, and just alerts the user when they may want to take a possible action.  Clicking the balloon should fire off some event I can catch and do something with.

(Is 'Notification' what it's actually called?  I get [a nice article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511448.aspx) about *when* to use Notifications, but nothing about *how* to use them.)

Answer (score 6):

The Windows function that drives these notifications is [`Shell_NotifyIcon()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159%28VS.85%29.aspx).

You should find an example of how to use it from Python in the `Lib\site-packages\win32\demos\win32gui_menu.py`.